# updating HTML5 video src in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

i have the next component:

```
class UserDetail extends Component {




    render() {
        if (!this.props.user) {
            return (<div></div>);
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div>{this.props.user.first} {this.props.user.last}</div>
                <div>Age: {this.props.user.age}</div>
                <div>Description: {this.props.user.description}</div>
                <video width="750" height="480" controls id='thevid'>
                  <source src={this.props.user.video} type="video/mp4"></source>
                </video>


            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

as you can see it return some details of picked user and then it display his details (that one of them is video).

when i press f+12 i can see that the src of the video change every time i pick new user, but actually the video is not updating.

in javascript i used to do:

```
document.getElementById('video').load();
```

and then the video is updating to the source link.

but in react i dont know how to do it.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the `src` on the `<source />` tag doesn't seem to do anything after it's already been set.

Either set the src of the video manually by using refs or a better way by passing the src to the `<video />` component.

```
 <video width="750" height="480" controls id='thevid' src={this.props.user.video} />
```